# pageReference.state.c__fieldValue is getting as undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, pagereference

In my Aura component, I am trying to access this URL value using below implementation:

```
var pageReference = component.get("v.pageReference");
component.set('v.fieldObj',decodeURIComponent(pageReference.state.c__fieldValue));
```

But I'm always getting `pageReference.state.c__fieldValue` value as undefined. I can see the value within the URL, but still unable to access it.

Here is the URL I have (tried to mask our actual fields and data):

> https://ourInstance.lightning.force.com/lightning/cmp/c__OUR_AURA_COMPONENT?c__new=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&c__sd=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&c__click=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&c__factors=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&c__price=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&c__carflag=true&c__survival=%5Bobject%20Object%5D&c__accept=%5Bobject%20Object%5D%2C%5Bobject%20Object%5D&c__flag=true&c__fieldValue%3D%25257B%252522firstReason%252522%25253A%252522Initial%252520Authorization%252522%25252C%252522csText%252522%25253A%252522Supply%252520Chain%252522%25252C%252522temporarySearchVal%252522%25253A%252522111332287%252522%25252C%252522whoId%252522%25253A%252522Supply%252520Chain%252522%25257D%26c__supplyNo%3D%26c__supId%3D11133287%26c__who%3DSupply%2520Chain%26c__relation%3D%26c__connection%3DOther%26c__contName%3DCVS%26c__inChk%26c__isCheckedFlag%3Dtrue%26uid%3D163232787003%26c__parentId%3Dctab5

Note: I can access other URL values the same way as above, but not this. My CMP is already set to `lightning:isUrlAddressable`. Any insights would greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you update the post with the url as well?

Comment: @glls Updated with the URL.

Comment: when exactly are you trying to access it? a specific event? or imperatively (liekk btn click)?

Comment: I am passing few properties from this Aura comp to my child LWC comp. One of them is - `handleNavigation` where I am trying to access the Aura-specific properties that are set within `doInit( )`.